# How to select and put into a String an attribute value of an element using XPath query in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am pretty new in **XPath** query into Java and I have the following problem:

I have a **org.jdom.Document documentXML** variable that contains the following XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <status>
    <id>0</id>
    <message>Operazione conclusa con successo</message>
  </status>
  <drivers>
    <drive id="MyID">
      <propery1 />
      <property2 />
      <property3 />
      <property4>0</property4>
      <sproperty5>104857600</property5>
      <property6 />
    </drive>
  </drivers>
</root>
```

I have to select the value inside the **id attribute** and put it into a String (so I have to put the "MyID" value inside a String)

In Java I have to something like this (that don't work):

```
org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter xmlOutputterCDATAContent = new org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());

xmlOutputter.output(documentXML, System.out);

xPath = XPath.newInstance("/root/drivers/drive/@id");
objectElement = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
driveId = objectElement.getValue();
System.out.println("ID " + objectElement.getValue() + " /ID");
```

So, as you can see the **documentXML** variable contains the previous XML code

I create an **XPath query** to access to the value of **id attribute** of the drive node, then I try to put this value into the **driveId** (that is a String object)

But in this way can't work and when I run this code I obtain the following error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jdom.Attribute cannot be cast to org.jdom.Element
```

What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Well "MyID" is an Attribute not an Element so I think you are doing the wrong cast.

Answer (score 1):

Like you already mentioned, the id you want to get is an **attribute**.

Hence, you just have to change your cast from `org.jdom.Element` to `org.jdom.Attribute`.
Then you can call `driveId.getValue()` to get the String value for id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jcabi-xml](http://xml.jcabi.com) and accomplish this in one line:

```
String id = new XMLDocument(xml).xpath("/root/drivers/drive/@id").get(0);
```